# vector into matrix armadillo

Tags: matlab, armadillo

I want to do something similar to `MATLAB`'s function:

```
mat = vec2mat(vec,matcol)
mat = vec2mat(vec,matcol,padding)
[mat,padded] = vec2mat(...)
```

but in armadillo c++ library, Do you know How?.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a function to that does that. I would email the devs and see what they have to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be so hard to achieve similar behavior with reshape I think:

```
mat vec2mat(vec V, size_t cols) {
    size_t rows = std::ceil(V.n_elems / double(cols));
    return V.reshape(cols, rows);// return the original vector as matrix
}
```

It's not exactly the same (it padds always with 0), but it's quite similar I think.